# Unable to run React Native App on Android emulator (CISO Anyconnect VPN + Proxy laptop)

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

I started with a basic template and tried running npx react-native run-android

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 896 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:installDebug
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Nexus_6_API_28(AVD) - 9' for app:debug
Installed on 1 device.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 9s
29 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 27 up-to-date
info Connecting to the development server...
info Starting the app on "emulator-5554"...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.awesomepro/.MainActivity }
```

It fails with error : Unable to load script :make sure you are either running metro :

And by clicking on Reload button: It fails with unable to connect the development server.

Note: When I diconnected the VPN agent it runs. But after connecting to VPN the issue occurs

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Yes. I have documented here https://www.nintyzeros.com/2021/08/react-native-installation-proxy.html

Comment: Had the same problem Here a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69983274/reactnative-access-denied-when-mac-is-connected-to-vpn/69983611#69983611