# ReactNative access denied when Mac is connected to VPN

Tags: ios, react-native, proxy, vpn, simulator

Launching application ReactNative on a ios simulator gives erros when Mac is connected to VPN :

Access Denied (policy_denied)

On device it's work fine, if a disable VPN it's works

I tried to delete all folded nodes_module, pods, ,lock files launch several times but still the same problem

I launch the app from xCode i also try to launch it from terminal but nothing changed

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On simulator i click on
cmd + d
configure bundle
after i put the ip adress of my Mac adress 192.168... and it works